# Reverse the array after a fixed position

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Given an ArrayList 'arr' of integers and a position 'm' . You have to reverse the array after that position.

Example

```
We have an Array arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and m = 3, considering O based indexing so the subarray   {5, 6} will be reversed and our output array will be {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5}
```

Constraints

```
1<=T<=10
0 <= M <= N <= 5*10^4
10^(-9) <= arr[i] <= 10^(9)
Time Limit: 1 second
```

for this question this is what I did

```
import java.util.* ;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution 
{
    
    public static void reverseArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int m)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<= m ; i++){
            nums.add(arr.get[i]);
        }
        int left = m+1;
        int right = arr.length -1;
        while(left<right){
            int temp = arr.get[left];
            arr.get[left] = arr.get[right];
            arr.get[right] = temp;

            teft++;
            right--;
        }
        for(int i = m+1; i< arr.length; i++){
            nums.add(arr.get[m+1]);
        }

    }
}
```

on running it shows this error

```
Compilation Failed
./Solution.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            nums.add(arr.get[i]);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable get
  location: variable arr of type ArrayList
./Solution.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        int right = arr.length -1;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable arr of type ArrayList
./Solution.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
            int temp = arr.get[left];
                          ^
  symbol:   variable get
  location: variable arr of type ArrayList
```

Can you help in identifying my mistake in the code and as well as how to read the compilation error like I'm not able to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an `ArrayList`. Its syntax is little bit different from `Array`.

To get a value: `arr.get(i)`

To get length: `arr.size()`

**Update:**

To update a value in `ArrayList`, you cannot do `arr.get(left) = arr.get(right)` or `arr.get(right) = temp`. Rather you have to do:

```
arr.set(left, arr.get(right));
arr.set(right, temp);
```

Comment: Thanks! after changing the required things... I'm still getting compilation error 
Compilation Failed
./Solution.java:19: error: unexpected type
            arr.get(left) = arr.get(right);
                   ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
./Solution.java:20: error: unexpected type
            arr.get(right) = temp;
                   ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
2 errors
Can you help?

Comment: @ImmortalSugimoto I have updated my answer, for your new error you mentioned. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void reverse(int[] arr, int m) {
    int lo = Math.max(0, m + 1);
    int hi = arr.length - 1;

    for (int i = lo, j = hi; i < j; i++, j--) {
        // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```java
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
reverse(arr, 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
```

---

In case you have a `ArrayList`, then you shuld do similar:

```java
public static void reverse(List<Integer> arr, int m) {
    int lo = Math.max(0, m + 1);
    int hi = arr.size() - 1;

    for (int i = lo, j = hi; i < j; i++, j--) {
        // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
        int tmp = arr.get(i);
        arr.set(i, arr.get(j));
        arr.set(j, tmp);
    }
}
```